# How can i re-set the frame-rate of avi file after its done?

Tags: c#, .net, avi, frame-rate

I had coded a program that records a screencast using AviFile Lib and set the framerate, but i need to adjust the framerate after the recording its done. How can i re-set the header of the avi-file changing the frame-rate of the avi file created?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library and sample app over on codeplex, it may help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library